# caching jquery .load url

Tags: jquery, caching

My question is about how (and if I should bother) to cache a URL that is referred to many times over.

```
$("#container").load("article.php #target");
```

Note that the selector expression appended to the URL (i.e., #target) is the only thing that varies.

```
$("#container").load("article.php #target1");
$("#container").load("article.php #target2");
$("#container").load("article.php #target3");
```

What I'm trying to figure out is how to cache as much of this as possible, for example (pseudo code):

```
var loadCache = $("#container").load("article.php") + "target";
```

Then later on I'd define target.

1) Is this doable?
2) If so, is there going to be a performance benefit?

Thank you kindly.

Comment: Check your browser's network tab. I would imagine the browser is already caching this for you. If not, you can use http headers to tell the browser to cache it.

Answer (score 0):

Set http header as Jason P suggested.
Set http headers on the response(either html or on the server, etc)

> cache-control: public